# Glassfish 4.x doesn't work on Windows 8.1

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish

i've been trying lately to run my web application on Glassfish, i tried with netbeans and intellij and both show the same error :
`could not start Glassfish server :DAS port is occupied while server is not running`

or

`Could not start GlassFish Server: Administrator port is occupied by null`

i'm sure that the port 4848 is not occupied (8080 too)

And when running intellij on Windows 7, it worked, so what's the problem when running it on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its a permission problem. You should check if the windows user you are using has the right permissions to start and modify GlassFish files.

Check the permissions of your domain folder (probably `<GLASSFISH_INSTALLATION>\glassfish\domains\domain1`), you should have all permissions (total control) on this folder. If this doesn't help, you may have to check the permissions of the whole `<GLASSFISH_INSTALLATION>` folder.

Other things to check:

- Windows Firewall
- check if ports are really free: `netstat -aon | find ":4848"`

Comment: it was a `permission denied` problem, i saw your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776798/glassfish-server-doesnt-start-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-lis) but the problem is when i add 127.0.0.1 myhostnameto the host file, under 127.0.0.1 localhost,
the `nslookup myhostname` still doesn't work , do u have any idea why please, and thank u

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea at the moment.